# cart.json error in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x

While checking error logs in hosting account, finding this error on few pages of cart.json not available
i have checked source page, file and never had this kind of file or link cart.json in it
Also its from 1 ip, but from few ips

anyone aware of same or can this be ignored.

```
    2022-11-15 09:15:54 UTC [apache][core:info] [pid 72672] [client 122.180.248.95:12148] AH00128: File does not exist: 
/home/u1846-1aoqgdzbvlbl/www/xyz.com/public_html/cart.json, referer: https://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_easyblog&view=entry&id=1&Itemid=1
```

Comment: It's possible that an attacker is trying to access said file from various pages on your site. If I'm not mistaken, this file is part of the Shopify CMS, so perhaps they're trying to exploit a security vulnerability within it. You may also notice people trying to access `your_domain.com/admin`, incase you're running a Wordpress site. These attackers crawl thousands of sites, multiple times, using various IPs. So always be sure to keep your Joomla and extensions up to date and follow the best security practices.

Comment: Oh is that so. Am not using shopify, is it possible to redirect cart.json to homepage or can i ignore it.

Comment: Yes, you can redirect to the homepage in your `.htaccess` file